# How to enable serial port on the Raspberry Pi Zero USB OTG port?

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, usb-otg

The Raspberry Pi Zero comes with USB OTG port. After some reading about OTG driver it seems that it could be configured as CDC device like serial port. So I was wondering if it is possible do so with the Pi Zero?

Answer (score 0):

To enable EtherNet over USB you need to:

1- you need to edit **cmdline.txt**.  Look for ***rootwait*** and add **modules-load=dwc2,g_ether** after it immediately.

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

2- edit /boot/config.txt

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

3- You need to specify address in **dhcpcd.config**

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.config
```

Now define IP address:

```
 interface usb0
           static ip_address=192.168.11.1 ## SAME AS ROUTERS 
           static routers=192.168.11.1 
           static domain_name_Servers=192.168.11.1
```

If you have two or more boards you want to connect to each other then you need to define same definition but with different IPs for each board.

```
interface usb0
       static ip_address=192.168.11.9 ### ANOTHER ADDRESS HERER
       static routers=192.168.11.1 
       static domain_name_Servers=192.168.11.1
```

Please check [this](https://technicaladventure.blogspot.com/2022/04/connecting-raspberry-pi-zero-w-with.html) article for detailed description