# How to use the USB OTG on an embedded system as an serial port?

Tags: serial-port, usb, embedded-linux

I searched and found similar quesiton:
[How to enable serial port on the raspberrypi zero USB OTG port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062133/how-to-enable-serial-port-on-the-raspberrypi-zero-usb-otg-port)

with no answer yet.

In my case it's not raspberry, it's an IFC6410 board.
I flashed the board with Linaro linux image provided by the vendor. I could use ethernet cable and ssh to communicate with the card. However, it is not very stable. I suspect there is something wrong with the network driver. Also, there are some other reasons for me to look for a way to communicate with the embedded system through a serial terminal, like ADB. However, looks like ADB is no longer an option on the ubuntu linux. I understand that with some "hardware" work, I should be able to use the 3-pin RS232 on board. But I look for something simpler or "softer"

So my question is: is there a "simple software way" to make use of the USB OTG as a  serial communication terminal? I made some research but don't think I am heading the right direction. Is there a common way that people doing this or it's just too complicated and not worth to do it?

The vendor also had an android image for this board which you can use adb through this usb otg to talk to the embedded. I don't know if linaro linux also have similar way?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt), it seems simple to use the USB OTG port as a gadget serial device, assuming the kernel is properly configured.  But this really doesn't replace a UART/USART console, which would be used by bootloaders and earlyprintk.

Comment: Hi sawdust, this is very interesting info to me. However I used android-tools-adbd since it's quicker. Looks like ttyGS0 appears after I install the android-tools-adbd. Maybe it's utilizing this driver.. Thanks for the info

Comment: *"Maybe it's utilizing this driver."* -- Yes, /dev/ttyGS0 is the node for the gadget serial device.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a tool  called adbd.
I ran
`apt-get install android-tools-adbd`  on my ifc6410 board
and modify `/etc/init/android-tools-adbd.conf` to board specific info makes the adb works. Now I can adb into my board.

include `start android-tools-adbd` at `/etc/rc.local` of the board makes it start when boot.